# How to use a custom type of Slice in a Receiver Method

Tags: go, types, slice

I am new to Golang, and I know that a Receiver Method should be called by reference not by value. But the weird thing is that after naming a slice type, this is not working!!

I named a set of processes as `Group`, where `Process` is a struct of whatever content.

```
type Group []Process
```

A `Group` has a set of related methods in which I use them commonly through receiver methods. This `Search` function is just a simple sample.

```
func (G *Group) Search(addr string) (*Process, error) {

    for _, ps := range *G {

        if ps.Address == addr {

            return &ps, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Group: Address Not found")
}
```

Then I call it by

```
p, err := group.Search(address)
```

p can be changed normally. But the changes are affecting only p (which is not really pointing to a slice element of the `Group`), not the slice element in `Group`.

**Question**: How to use a custom type of Slice in a Receiver Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're using a slice type as a receiver. There *is* something wrong with your loop and how you're returning a pointer. Change

```
for _, ps := range *G {
    if ps.Address == addr {
        return &ps, nil
    }
}
```

into

```
for i, ps := range *G {
    if ps.Address == addr {
        return &(*G)[i], nil
    }
}
```

and it should work — you'll be returning a pointer into the slice, instead of a pointer to a local variable.